# ¿Como puedo obtener en codeigniter un COUNT() o un SUM() de un mismo valor?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, codeigniter

Pues, eso... estoy realizando una aplicación con Codeigniter, y todo va muy bien, pero para presentar un resumen de datos estoy en busca de una solución para obtener la suma de la cantidad de veces que valor es positivo (pero en este caso es literalmente "si") dentro de una consulta con GROUP BY.

La consulta en mi modelo:

```
// Consulta para programas
public function get_datos('programas,programas'.'nombre,registros','registros.programa','registros.monto','registros.capacitacion',$limite,$offset) {

    $this->db->select('programas.*,COUNT(programas.nombre) as acciones,SUM(registros.monto) as inversion,COUNT(registros.capacitacion) as capacitados');
    $this->db->from('programas');
    $this->db->join('registros','programas.nombre = registros.programa','left');
    //$this->db->where('registros.capacitacion','si'); 
    $this->db->group_by('programas.nombre');
    $this->db->having('acciones >= 0',null,false);
    $this->db->order_by('programas.nombre','asc');
    $this->db->limit($limite,$offset);
    $consulta = $this->db->get();

    if ($consulta->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $consulta->result();
    }

}
```

Esta función me permite mostrar un listado de programas agrupando los registros inherentes a cada uno, cada programas tiene datos de inversión, acciones y capacitación. Como ya mencioné, agrupa correctamente y muestra cada programa con el numero de acciones que corresponden a cada uno, sumando sus montos de inversión, pero no encuentro como mostrar la suma de los programas que ya tienen capacitación sin descartar los registros que no tienen aún.

Con un WHERE o un LIKE me suprime los registros los que tienen valor "no" y obtengo esto:

```
PROGRAMA   | ACCIONES | CAPACITACIÓN REALIZADA | INVERSIÓN
Programa 1 | 2        | 2                      | $23,500.67
Programa 2 | 0        | 0                      | $0
Programa 3 | 1        | 1                      | $42,570.93
```

Si suprimo el WHERE, obviamente sólo cuenta todos los campos al igual que "acciones":

```
PROGRAMA   | ACCIONES | CAPACITACIÓN REALIZADA | INVERSIÓN
Programa 1 | 3        | 3                      | $23,500.67
Programa 2 | 0        | 0                      | $0
Programa 3 | 6        | 6                      | $42,570.93
```

Y lo que necesito es esto (el programa 1 tiene 3 eventos registrados, de los cuales sólo 2 han realizado su capacitación):

```
PROGRAMA   | ACCIONES | CAPACITACIÓN REALIZADA | INVERSIÓN
Programa 1 | 3        | 2                      | $23,500.67
Programa 2 | 0        | 0                      | $0
Programa 3 | 6        | 1                      | $42,570.93
```

Probé algunas cosas como IF(COUNT(campo),'si'), pero parece no funcionar en Codeigniter.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea, se los agradeceré bastante. Saludos.

Comment: Aún ocupo de sus comentarios. Gracias.

Comment: No se si ya habrás solucionado esto, pero probaste primero realizar la consulta directo en mysql?, de ser así puedes ejecutarla directo sin necesidad del database helper de codeigniter

Comment: Hey, gracias por tu respuesta Oscar. En realidad aún no lo resuelvo como deseo. No lo había visto desde esa perspectiva que comentas, na verdad es que si pensé en probar directamente en MySQL, simplemente para ver si lo que estaba pensando hacer funcionaba de esa manera, pero pensé que sería en vano si no lograba ejecutarlo después con el helper de CI, pero si si es posible usar la consulta directa tal vez podré conseguirlo. Gracias, comentaré el resultado. Saludos.

Comment: Había visto tu pregunta hace semanas pero no podía comentar debido a que me faltaba puntuación, te hago saber que tuve el mismo problema y es a causa del join, por lo menos yo no logre hacer un join con el helper de CI